Do maps fill out while exploring underground?
When a craftable map is held, exploring the world will fill out areas of the map with an image of the world surface. Will said map be updated the same way if held while exploring underground? Or will it only work when exploring the surface?

Yes, they work even exploring underground, only your X-Z coordinates are considered by the map, the Y doesn't really matter.
